# How to response the relationship data in fastAPI?

Tags: rest, sqlalchemy, relationship, fastapi, pydantic

I am using fastAPI for backend in which there are two schemas

```py
import datetime as dt
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class TradeDetails(BaseModel):
    buySellIndicator: str = Field(description="A value of BUY for buys, SELL for sells.")
    price: float = Field(description="The price of the Trade.")
    quantity: int = Field(description="The amount of units traded.")

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class Trade(BaseModel):
    asset_class: Optional[str] = Field(alias="assetClass", default=None,
                                       description="The asset class of the instrument traded. E.g. Bond, Equity, FX...etc")
    counterparty: Optional[str] = Field(default=None,
                                        description="The counterparty the trade was executed with. May not always be available")
    instrument_id: str = Field(alias="instrumentId",
                               description="The ISIN/ID of the instrument traded. E.g. TSLA, AAPL, AMZN...etc")
    instrument_name: str = Field(alias="instrumentName", description="The name of the instrument traded.")
    trade_date_time: dt.datetime = Field(alias="tradeDateTime", description="The date-time the Trade was executed")
    trade_details: TradeDetails = Field(alias="tradeDetails",
                                        description="The details of the trade, i.e. price, quantity")
    trade_id: str = Field(alias="tradeId", default=None, description="The unique ID of the trade")
    trader: str = Field(description="The name of the Trader")

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

and for these two schemas I have created two tables in my database with relationships

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float, DateTime, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from database import Base


class TradeDetails(Base):
    __tablename__ = "trade_details"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    buySellIndicator = Column(String)
    price = Column(Float)
    quantity = Column(Integer)
    trades = relationship("Trade", back_populates='trade_details')


class Trade(Base):
    __tablename__ = "trade"

    trade_id = Column(String, primary_key=True, index=True)
    trader = Column(String)
    trade_details_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("trade_details.id"))
    trade_details = relationship("TradeDetails", back_populates='trades')
    asset_class = Column(String)
    counterparty = Column(String)
    instrument_id = Column(Integer)
    instrument_name = Column(String)
    trade_date_time = Column(DateTime)
```

Now I am performing CRUD operations.

When I am trying to create trade this is how request body looks like
[image]

But when I execute the post method to create trade response body don't return tradeDetails data which is nested in the trade model
[image]

The method I am using to post
[image]

What's the mistake I am doing let me know and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code + details about the issue you're facing. Your concern seems to be pretty broad. Why don't you try narrowing down your Q to one specific aspect?

Comment: Alternatively, we can hop into a chat and dive deeper into your code if you'd like. SO has chat capability for this.